# Loop through a JSON array for specific data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through my json array and get the ItemName and Prices according to category when i select a particular category : Delicious Treats, Decoration and Entertainment and display them in a multiple drop down list. the code i wrote is getting all ItemName and prices for all categories in one select tag. 
heres my code

```
function data() {
var text = '{"DataArray":[{"ItemName":"Salmon Puffs","Price":5,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Beans on Toast Sandwich","Price":200,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Whole Mashed Potatoes","Price":50,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Calamari","Price":20,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Egyptian Decor Pack","Price":300,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Marie Biscuits","Price":80,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Middle Eastern Decor Pack","Price":390,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Star Wars Decor Pack","Price":360,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Hipster Decor Pack","Price":350,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Pears shaped liked Apples","Price":1000,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Flowers","Price":20,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Dance Floor","Price":60,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Clowns","Price":20.35,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Fire Dancers","Price":80,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Cantina Band","Price":2000,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Improved Salmon Puffs","Price":5,"Category":"Delicious Treats"}]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

}

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.DataArray.length; i++)
    {
        addOption(document.drop_list.item, obj.DataArray[i].Price, obj.DataArray[i].ItemName);
    }
```

Any assistance will be highly appreciated. thanks

This is what i was explaining
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what `and get the ItemName and Prices according to category when i select a particular category` means. Do you mean like a dropdown menu with multiple [`<optgroup>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)? I'll just write an answer assuming that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just...

```
if ( obj.DataArray[i].Category == 'Delicious Treats' ) 
    addOption(document.drop_list.item, obj.DataArray[i].Price, obj.DataArray[i].ItemName);
```

Comment: it worked thanks so much. how about to populate these properties in check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is getting updated inside the `data` function. So before executing `data` need to be called.

Here is a snippet which is logging `price` & `itemName`

```js
function data() {
  var text = '{"DataArray":[{"ItemName":"Salmon Puffs","Price":5,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Beans on Toast Sandwich","Price":200,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Whole Mashed Potatoes","Price":50,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Calamari","Price":20,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Egyptian Decor Pack","Price":300,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Marie Biscuits","Price":80,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Middle Eastern Decor Pack","Price":390,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Star Wars Decor Pack","Price":360,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Hipster Decor Pack","Price":350,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Pears shaped liked Apples","Price":1000,"Category":"Delicious Treats"},{"ItemName":"Flowers","Price":20,"Category":"Decoration"},{"ItemName":"Dance Floor","Price":60,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Clowns","Price":20.35,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Fire Dancers","Price":80,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Cantina Band","Price":2000,"Category":"Entertainment"},{"ItemName":"Improved Salmon Puffs","Price":5,"Category":"Delicious Treats"}]}';

  obj = JSON.parse(text);
}
data();
for (i = 0; i < obj.DataArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(obj.DataArray[i].Price, obj.DataArray[i].ItemName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do. Let me know if this is incorrect.

```js
var obj = {
  "DataArray": [
    {
      "ItemName": "Salmon Puffs",
      "Price": 5,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Beans on Toast Sandwich",
      "Price": 200,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Whole Mashed Potatoes",
      "Price": 50,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Calamari",
      "Price": 20,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Egyptian Decor Pack",
      "Price": 300,
      "Category": "Decoration"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Marie Biscuits",
      "Price": 80,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Middle Eastern Decor Pack",
      "Price": 390,
      "Category": "Decoration"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Star Wars Decor Pack",
      "Price": 360,
      "Category": "Decoration"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Hipster Decor Pack",
      "Price": 350,
      "Category": "Decoration"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Pears shaped liked Apples",
      "Price": 1000,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Flowers",
      "Price": 20,
      "Category": "Decoration"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Dance Floor",
      "Price": 60,
      "Category": "Entertainment"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Clowns",
      "Price": 20.35,
      "Category": "Entertainment"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Fire Dancers",
      "Price": 80,
      "Category": "Entertainment"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Cantina Band",
      "Price": 2000,
      "Category": "Entertainment"
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "Improved Salmon Puffs",
      "Price": 5,
      "Category": "Delicious Treats"
    }
  ]
};

var arr = obj.DataArray;

var select = document.createElement('select');
var map = {};

function addOption(optgroup, price, name) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  
  option.textContent = '$' + price.toFixed(2) + ': ' + name;
  
  optgroup.appendChild(option);
}

arr.forEach(function (item) {
  var optgroup = map[item.Category];

  if (!optgroup) {
    select.appendChild(map[item.Category] = optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup'));
    optgroup.setAttribute('label', item.Category);
  }
  
  addOption(optgroup, item.Price, item.ItemName);
});

document.body.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: its correct but the in this case im populating it in a way to get item names according to selected categories

Comment: @Felix I don't understand what you mean by that. Could you update your question to show what you expect the resulting behavior to be? Preferably some HTML you expect to be generated, or whatever.

Comment: i have attached a screen shot of what i explained